# Constructive Counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How many 3-digit numbers have a property that the first digit is at least the twice the second digit?
I looked at the solutions, but is says second digit 0 and the cases of it's
first digit is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 but I don't get it since 0 times something is always 0 anyways

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  For a three digit number, the first digit can not be $0$.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: No, so my question was that in the solution, when the second digit is 0 it said the first digit can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and I don't get since 0 times something is always 0.

Comment: Right, since $0$ times something is always $0$, then "twice $0$" is $0$. Certainly $1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9 \ge 2\cdot0 = 0$.

Comment: Right...but each of those digits is indeed "at least $0$".

Comment: QuantumPi-- Does the solution also discuss when second digit is other things than $0$ ? Like second digit $1$ and so on.

Comment: Yes, I get it when the second digit is 1 the first digit can be 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's turn this into something more Mathematical:

> the first digit is at least the twice the second digit

This can be rephrased into "The second digit is $k$ and the first digit is $\geq 2k$

If the first digit is $0$ then we need any number greater than $2(0)=0$,

We have $1\geq0$ so this works for any number starting $1$

Comment: The rephrasing should say the first digit is $\geq 2k$. So for instance if $k=1$ then the first digit could be 2.  But since the first digit of a 3-digit number is never 0, when $k=0$ then the first digit is $1$ or more.

Comment: that is correct, I edited it before but looks like I didn't save